# Table colspan and rowspan breaking in FireFox but not Chrome

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I currently have an interesting UI bug happening in Firefox. When the page is rendered in Chrome the table works as expected. Below is a sample HTML page with a bootstrap cdn if you would like to see the problem in the browser.

Run this in both browsers to see the difference.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>

    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div style="margin-top: 10px;">

    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="1" rowspan="2">ethbp</th>
            <th colspan="1" rowspan="2">duo-iujo</th>
            <th colspan="2" rowspan="0">CHUE</th>
            <th colspan="5" rowspan="0">aeueua aeuaeu</th>
            <th colspan="4" rowspan="0">aoeua aeuae</th>
            <th colspan="9" rowspan="0">aeuaeuaeuaeua</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">aoeu aeua</th>
            <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">aeu aeua</th>
            <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">aeuaeuaeu</th>
            <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">aeu aeu aeuaeu</th>
            <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">aeu aeu</th>
            <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">aeuaeuae</th>
            <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">near aeu</th>
            <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">eui</th>
            <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">uei</th>
            <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">euer</th>
            <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">aoeu</th>
            <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">eua</th>
            <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">loe</th>
            <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">oeu</th>
            <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">uou</th>
            <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">sec events</th>
            <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">evn aoeuaeo</th>
            <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">euoe auae</th>
            <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">euue oeueuo</th>
            <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">othre aeuae aeuaeu</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firefox doesn't like your `rowspan=0` attribute.  Change to `rowspan=1` and it renders like Chrome.

example:
https://jsfiddle.net/tyybbkah/

Answer (score 1):

Update your rowspan="0" to rowspan="2" on all of them.

"Using rowspan="0" (will only work in Firefox and Opera 12 and earlier):"
says
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp

Answer (score 0):

No need to write rowspan="1" or rowspan="0" and colspan="1" or colspan="0" for unnecessary requirement
Omit all those

```
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="1" rowspan="2">ethbp</th>
            <th colspan="1" rowspan="2">duo-iujo</th>
            <th colspan="2" rowspan="0">CHUE</th>
            <th colspan="5" rowspan="0">aeueua aeuaeu</th>
            <th colspan="4" rowspan="0">aoeua aeuae</th>
            <th colspan="9" rowspan="0">aeuaeuaeuaeua</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">aoeu aeua</th>
            <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">aeu aeua</th>
            <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">aeuaeuaeu</th>
            <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">aeu aeu aeuaeu</th>
            <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">aeu aeu</th>
            <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">aeuaeuae</th>
            <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">near aeu</th>
            <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">eui</th>
            <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">uei</th>
            <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">euer</th>
            <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">aoeu</th>
            <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">eua</th>
            <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">loe</th>
            <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">oeu</th>
            <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">uou</th>
            <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">sec events</th>
            <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">evn aoeuaeo</th>
            <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">euoe auae</th>
            <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">euue oeueuo</th>
            <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">othre aeuae aeuaeu</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

Check this fiddle
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bed59yt3/)